# PHP. Помощь с алгоритмом

Tags: php, база-данных, алгоритм

На сайте реализована функция определения города и региона по ip. Так вот, нужно чтобы у каждого города или региона выводилась определенная информация. Нужен алгоритм. Ведь это совсем не удобно для каждого города вбивать информацию, их сотни. Можно конечно сделать множественный выбор списка (где выбираются города), но тогда как это все записать в базу, ведь города не должны повторяться. Например, я вбиваю информацию для всей Московской области, а кто-то отдельно для Москвы, так не должно быть. Должно быть так, один город = один текст.

Пример: Допустим, админ сайта хочет чтобы у каждого города выводился свой баннер. Он заходит в админку выбирает город и указывает какой баннер выводить. Но это не удобно, городов сотня, каждому вбивать город не удобно. Мне б хотя бы пример.

Comment: Считаю, что вопрос вообще не задан.

Comment: @ilyaplot, `Нужен алгоритм`?

Comment: @ilyaplot, значит жмете на `закрыть` и выбираете нужный пункт из представленных.

Comment: Вопрос ни о чем. Откуда должна выводится информация? Нужен алгоритм на пополнение базы или на вывод информации? Если не вбивать информацию, то тогда выход - парсить с сайтов?? Города могут повторяться по названию, сделайте идентификатор, например, привязав к почтовому индексу города. В общем, конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Берёте сайт - этот (http://ipgeobase.ru) или любой другой, который определяет город по IP - шлете ему запрос, определяете город. Выдаёте список пользователю на уточнение, как это делает Авито (вы в этом городе?) и записываете его адрес с выбором в БД. При следующем заходе определяется автоматом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В дополнение к списку городов и их ip (для определения города - то, что как я понял у вас уже есть) вам нужно добавить дерево самих городов/районов/областей, чтоб понимать, какой город в какой более общий "узел" входит.

Тогда у вас не будет дублей и можно будет размещать баннер как для конкретного города, так и для целого района в случае, когда не хочется перечислять все города района или области.

Читать надо начать с деревьев в теории графов https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2)

В базе это реализуется разными способами. Самый банальный - завести в таблице городов ещё одно поле - "выше-стоящий объект" (parent_id) и через это поле помечать какой город в какой более крупный объект вложен.

```
Россия
  Тверская область
    Тверь
    Кашинский район
      город Кашин
  Башкортостан
    Уфа
    Куюргазинский район
      город Кумертау
```

и т.д.

Определив по ip конкретный город, просто проверь наличие баннера для него. Если пусто - проверяй для города, который расположен выше (более общий случай), ещё выше и ещё. Пока не доберёшься до самого верхнего узла. Как только нашёл что показать - показываешь.

Comment: Все это реализовано уже, кроме последнего абзаца. Последний абзац то что нужно.